# How reliable is SQL server replication?

Tags: sql-server, replication

We have a database on SQL Server 2000 which should be truncated from time to time. It looks like the easiest solution would be to create a duplicate database and copy the primary database there. Then the primary database may be safely truncated by specially tailored stored procedures.

One way replication would guarantee that the backup database contains all updates from the primary one.

We plan to use backup database for reporting and primary for operative data.
Primary database will be truncated at night once in 2 days.
Database is several gigabytes. Only several tables are quite large (1-2 mln rows)

What are possible pitfalls? How reliable would such a solution be? Will it slow down the primary database?

**Update:** Variant with DTS for doing copying sounds good but has own disadvantages. It requires quite robust script which would run for about an hour to copy updated rows. There is also issue with integrity constraints in primary database which would make truncating it non-trivial task. Because of this replication cold straighten things up considerably.

It is also possible but not quite good variant to use union VIEW because system which woks mostly in unattended mode whiteout dedicated support personnel. It is related issue but not technical though.

Answer (score 4):

While replication is usually robust, there are times where it can break and require a refresh.  Managing and maintaining replication can become complicated.  Once the primary database is truncated, you'll have to make sure that action is not replicated.  You may also need an improved system of row identification as after you've truncated the primary database tables a couple of times, you'll still have a complete history in your secondary database.

There is a performance hit on the publisher (primary) as extra threads have to run to read the transaction log.  Unless you're under heavy load at the moment, you likely won't notice this effect.  Transaction log management can become more important also.

Instead, I'd look at a different solution for your problem.  For example, before truncating, you can take a backup of the database, and restore it as a new database name.  You then have a copy of the database as it was before the truncation, and you can query both at once using three-part names.

You've mentioned that the purpose of the secondary data is to keep report off.  In this case you can create a view like SELECT * FROM Primary.dbo.Table UNION ALL SELECT * FROM SecondaryDBJune2008.dbo.Table UNION ALL SELECT * FROM SecondaryDBOctober2008.dbo.Table.  You wouild then need to keep this view up to date whenever you perform a truncate.

The other alternative would be to take a snapshot of the current data before truncation and insert it into a single reporting database.  Then you'd just have the Primary and the Historical databases - no need to modify views once they're created.

How much data are we talking about in GB?

As you're planning to perform the truncation once every two days, I'd recommend the second alternative, snapshotting the data before truncation into a single Historical database.  This can be easily done with a SQL Agent job, without having to worry about replication keeping the two sets of data in synch.

Comment: We need all old data avilable for reporting. So backup/restore would not help.

Comment: I've updated with some ideas on how you could still report from a backup/restore.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use replication for this.  We have a fairly complex replication setup running with 80+ branches replicating a few tables to one central database.  When connectivity goes down for a few days, the data management issues are hair raising.

If you want to archive older data, rather use DTS.  You can then build the copying and truncation/deletion of data into the same DTS package, setting it so that the deletion only happens if the copy was successful.

Comment: Unfortunately without replication things getting complicated also. But good side is that they are complex up-front what means that one copy script done there are much less troubles later.